# Android picasso resize image to screen width

Tags: android, image, image-resizing, picasso

I am using picasso to resize my background image to fill the screen width (not adjust the image height).

The problem is, that even though I set the image width to the same as the screen width, the image does not fill to the horizontal edges, there is a gap. At 800dp the gap is 35dp.

here is my code

```
ImageView imgBackground = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgBackground);

Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.morn_blur_bg);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int displayWidth = size.x;
int height = size.y;
int width = 0;

//Log.d("CP", "Screen width="+displayWidth);
//Log.d("CP", "Image width=" + bMap.getWidth());

if (bMap.getWidth() < displayWidth) {
    width = displayWidth;
} else {
    width = bMap.getWidth();
}

Log.d("CP", "New width=" + width);

Picasso.with(v.getContext())
        .load(R.drawable.morn_blur_bg)
        .resize(width, height)
        .into(imgBackground);
```

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layRoot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <!--Background image-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

If I hardcode the width to 835dp the image fills the display, but of course this will not work across devices. :-)

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use below Custom Image view at the place of ImageView:

```
    public class DynamicImageView extends ImageView {

   public DynamicImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

  @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final Drawable d = this.getDrawable();

    if (d != null) {
        // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
    final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = (int) Math.ceil(width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth());
        this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
 }
}
```

this may solve your problem!

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion, however this appears to adjust the height and width, I need to adjust the width only. I can't adjust the height. I attempted to use this code, but keep the original height of the image, but this causes the same bars on either side of the image

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Picasso.with(v.getContext())
        .load(R.drawable.morn_blur_bg)
        .resize(width, height)
        .fit()
        .into(imgBackground);

Comment: Hi, won't fit() cause the image to stretch in both width and height?

Comment: This also causes an exception that resize() cannot be used with fit().

Answer (score 0):

Try using **.CenterCrop**

```
            Picasso.with(v.getContext())
    .load(R.drawable.morn_blur_bg)
    .resize(width, height)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imgBackground);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this still leaves whiite bars down either side of the image

Comment: @Rival Have you tried increasing the width? Can you take a screen shot so I can see?

Comment: Hi Errol, yeah I had to increase the width and then crop it, but it seemed odd to make an image 835dp on a 800dp screen. That filled the gap. I ended up having to drop picasso, as the image displayed different on different devices.

Comment: @Rival what do you mean displayed differently, I'm using Picasso on about 8000 devices and it works perfectly. Another thing you should consider  using Picasso is that it handles all image caching so you don't eat up network bandwidth (provided you are using images that are from the Internet)

Comment: I need the height to not change on my background images. However on a couple of devices the height seems to be slightly off. maybe it is something to do with the imageview xml rather than picasso? could you suggest some settings for the imageview so that it crops but does not resize, and the image is center top? cheers

Comment: @Rival if you dont want it to resize then dont use the .resize function.